# Calling py in Ubuntu leading to collections.abc Deprecation Warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

So, I have just installed Ubuntu for the first time and am trying to run a very simple Python project. Upon the first run, I got the collections.abc Deprecation Warning, which prompt me to make sure my project was up to date.

After additional investigation, I found out that just running the py command leads to this Deprecation Warning, as seen below:

```
Documents$ py

/usr/bin/py:16: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
  from collections import Iterable
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? I already removed Python 2 from the system and made sure that Python 3 is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Found this concerning your issue:
https://programmerah.com/solved-python3-10-error-cannot-import-name-iterable-from-collections-46165/

also, in Unix/Linux, the call to the Python environment is "python" not py.

Comment: Please share the essential points from the link here in your answer